# Why is this the domain of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a function that goes like this: $f(x)=\sqrt{x-6\sinh(\ln(x))}$.
I have calculated the domain, and in the end, I get that x should be smaller or equal to $\pm\sqrt{3/2}$, but the soultion should be that is either smaller or equal than $-\sqrt{3/2}$, or bigger than 0 and smaller or equal to $+\sqrt{3/2}$.
Why is that so?

Thanks for you help

Comment: What is sh? Anyway, this kind of situation is rather typical: think of $\sqrt{x^2-1}$. You need $x^2-1 \geq 0$. $x^2-1=0$ at $x=\pm 1$. In between those two numbers, $x^2-1<0$. On the outside of both numbers, $x^2-1>0$. So you get a domain of $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$.

Comment: $\pm\sqrt{3/2}$ is not a number, but two numbers $\sqrt{3/2}$ and $-\sqrt{3/2}$ written in a short form. You have to decide, or better, to further interpret this result.

Comment: First of all, $\pm \sqrt{\frac 32}$ are two numbers. If you can't say $x \le \pm \sqrt {\frac 32}$ because if $x \le - \sqrt{\frac 32}=$ it *has* to be less than $+\sqrt{\frac 32}$ because $-\sqrt{\frac 32} < \sqrt{\frac 32}$ so that is redundant.   If you think of what these inequalities *mean* and not just how to manipulate them the answer might be clearer.

Comment: For $\ln x$ to be defined then $x$ must be greater than $0$ so $x \le 0$ is impossible so getting $x \le -\sqrt{\frac 32} < 0$ can not possibly correct.  So either the solution is wrong or you didn't write the question correctly.  Probably the latter as none of us seem to know what $sh$ means?

Comment: Is “sh” supposed to mean “$\sinh$”?

Comment: my bad, sh is supposed to mean sinh, I just now realised that we use a different abbreviation for the function. Yes, it is sinh.

Comment: @fleablood: Your comment is really good, but you should notice that $\log(-x)$ is $\log(x)+i\pi$ and that $\sinh(x+i\pi)\in\mathbb R$. So maybe we can allow $x$ to be less than $0$. In addition, you can use the fact that  $e^x$ and $\log$ are inverse functions and then $$6\sinh(\log(x))=3\frac{x^2-1}{x},$$ so the question is reduced to study the inequality $$x-3\frac{x^2-1}{x}\geq 0.$$

Comment: That would make sense if $sh$ means $\sinh$.  I simply assumed be the level of the question we were doing real numbers only.  But... um... if we are using complex numbers than why are we assuming the $\sqrt{}$ must be real?  And if this question is that sophisticated, why are we using the naive notation that the domain is every possible real number, rather than the more accurate the domain is a intrinsic property of the function and needs to be stated or else the function has not been properly defined.

Comment: But yous @Dog_69, you are correct.

Comment: @fleablood: I know what you mean and I'm completely agree with you. I only wanted to noticed that posibility.

Comment: Actually... I'm waffling back.  I think the solution is incorrect.  I think the text assumed $\sinh(\ln x) = \frac {e^{\ln x} - e^{-\ln x}}2 = \frac {x + \frac 1x}2$, and did not realize that $x$ must be positive because this is a real function of a composition of real functions.  So such the solution is $(0, \sqrt{\frac 32})$... In my opinion.... and, yes,  sometimes math *can* be a matter of opinion.....

Comment: Although, had complex numbers been acceptable the question as $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined as $\sqrt{x - 6\sinh(Ln(x))}$ where $Ln:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ and $\sqrt:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$; then what is the domain of $f$ would be a fair question.  Although this fail all style points.  And and mathematician in "real life" who would *want* such a function would simply write it as $\sqrt{x -3\frac {x^2 -1}x}$.